# Drupal 7 | Associate dynamic user to a content type

Tags: nodes, users

I have a  content type "Article", with a field "author".

Is it possible to assign users with "writers" role dynamically with this field ?

The goal is to display in the article node, a link which redirects to the writer(user) profile.

For example :

-Article Title

-MM/DD/YYYY

-Written by : randomWritter (dynamic link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module will enable you to do that.

It allows you to create fields and associate them with existing content/users on the site. It also features integration with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) so you can have more complex logic to filter out the available options.
The field can also be displayed as an autocomplete.

Comment: Views with Views bulk operations can do the magic